# Qt C++ - How to successfully pass data to child process?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I wrote a short piece of test software, whose goal is to actually start my python virtual environment via a childprocess and execute some commands in that process. It seems the child process never receives the data.

The code bellow does 2 things: pass data, ie the string "John" to the child process and reading the log file every time the string is passed (to check whether eg the command was properly understood).

In my terminal I type this (I intentionally execute an incorrect command for testing purposes):

```
   $ script -f -c python2 python.log
   Script started, file is python.log
   Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
   [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> John
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

and my python.log file now contains (as expected and wanted):

```
   Script started on Don 17 Aug 2017 01:04:54 CEST
   Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
   [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> John
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'John' is not defined
   >>>
```

the corresponding code which is supposed to replicate this behaviour:

when pushing a button on my gui this code gets executed:

```
    void MainWindow::mainFunction()
   {
       QFile myfile("/home/John/Desktop/python.log");
       QTextStream input(&myfile);
       if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
           QMessageBox::information(0, "error", myfile.errorString());
       }

       QProcess p;    //childprocess
       QStringList params;
       qint64 successFailWrite;
       qRegisterMetaType<QProcess::ProcessError>("QProcess::ProcessError");
       connect(&p, &QProcess::errorOccurred, qApp, &QApplication::aboutQt );
       //connect(&p, &QProcess::started, qApp, &QApplication::aboutQt);
       params<<"-f"<<"-c"<<"python2 python.log";
       qDebug()<<"parameters: "<<params;
       p.start("script", params);
       while(!p.waitForStarted())
       {qDebug()<<"waiting for started";}


       while(1)
       {
           successFailWrite = p.write("John", 1);

           while(!input.atEnd())
           {
               QString line = input.readLine();
               qDebug()<<"read: "<<line;
           }
       }
   }
```

When executing this code, my python.log file is always empty yet the successFailWrite variable is 1, which means it siccessfully wrote the string to the process. What is also strange is that when I replace

```
       p.start("script", params);
```

with: p.start("scriptttt", params);

nothing changes at all, the aboutQt SLOT doesn't get activated and I can't see any error message anywhere.
[According to the Qt documents I should be able to interface with my process using write() just like an IODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details)

What am I doing incorrectly?

**EDIT:** params<<"-f"<<"-c"<<"python2"<<"python.log"; doesn't work neither.

I can however see that this happens when my code is being executed:

```
$ ps aux | grep python

John+  7436  0.0  0.0  22352  2716 ?        S    11:56   0:00 script -f -c python2 python.log
John+  7437  0.5  0.1  31648  6924 pts/20   Ss+  11:56   0:00 python2
John+  7439  0.0  0.0  14540  1020 pts/0    S+   11:56   0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

Comment: What do you think `p.write("John", 1)` actually [does](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) though?

Comment: @G.M. write the string to the process. Note that I read the docs... But something is still wrong. I can see using `$ps aux` that the process is being started, yet it looks like the process doesn't receive my data because my file is always empty. But on the other side the function returns 1, which means it successfully wrote the string to the process. So something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Please look at the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) again.  The second parameter is the maximum number of bytes to write.  In addition, you'll probably need to write a newline character before the interpreter will accept the input.

Comment: @G.M. I am affraid there is still something wrong: successFailWrite = p.write("John\n", 30);. This didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems.  Firstly, as pointed out in the comments, the following code...

```
p.write("John", 1);
```

will only write a single character.  Since you have a null terminated string simply use the [`QIODevice::write`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-1) overload that accepts that and remember to include a newline character...

```
p.write("John\n");
```

More importantly though, you have...

```
params << "-f" << "-c" << "python2 python.log";
```

You need to split "python2 python.log" -- that's two separate arguments.  Try...

```
params << "-f" << "-c" << "python2" << "python.log";
```

With the above changes the code works fine for me.

Comment: OK, my bad you were right. It actually created a file located at the place where the "exe" while I was looking at an old file with the same name on my Desktop. The file being written was not the same as the file I read from. Accepted your answer, thx.

Comment: Where is your event loop?  Without that nothing will happen.

Comment: event loop for what exactly? Currently it reads and writes. What do you mean?

Comment: it writes and reads correctly because I added a delay, but I see what you mean.